# Clicking on One Button Cancels a Click Event of Another (Outer) Button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a post that allows users to comment but the comment's `textarea` is hidden by default until the user clicks on `Comment` button. The comment textarea has a 
`Send` and `Cancel` buttons. The `Cancel` button hides the `textarea` but after that, clicking on `Comment` button doesn't work again until you refresh the page.

**HTML**:

```
<div class='post'>
    <div class='p_body'>
        <div class = 'comment_body_wrapper'>
            <div class = 'comment_wrapper'>
                <textarea class="comment_content" rows = '2' maxlength="480" name="comment_content" placeholder="Your thoughts on this..."></textarea>
                <div class = 'comment_buttons_wrapper'>
                    <div class='comment_buttons'>
                        <button class="submit_comment btn" type="submit">Send</button>
                        <button class="comment_cancel_button btn" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'post_footer'>
            <button class='btn post_comment' value = '1'>Comment </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('body').on('click', '.post_comment', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $comment=$this.closest('.post').find('.comment_body_wrapper').find('.comment_wrapper');
    $comment.slideToggle(); 
    $comment.find('.comment_content').focus();
})

$('body').on('click', '.comment_cancel_button', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.comment_body_wrapper').hide();
})
```

If I click on the `Comment` button it sure toggles it (display or hide) but clicking on `Cancel` removes this event. The `comment_cancel_button`
hides `comment_wrapper` as expected but after that clicking on `Comment` doesn't `slideToggle`s it. I have to refresh. How do I handle this the right way?

Comment: Just a side-note. Use `document` in preference to `'body'` if nothing closer is available to the changing elements. `'body'` has bugs relating to styling (causing click events to not fire)

Comment: Okay, you mean `$(document).ready(function(){....})` is not enough? This didn't solve my problem though.

Comment: No I did not mean document ready... Basically you hide one thing, then show its child... Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding `'.comment_body_wrapper'`, but showing its child `'.comment_wrapper'`:)

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mjqs6ces/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.post_comment', function(){
    console.log('.post_comment');
    var $this = $(this);
    var $comment=$this.closest('.post').find('.comment_body_wrapper .comment_wrapper');
    $comment.slideToggle(); 
    $comment.find('.comment_content').focus();
});


$(document).on('click', '.comment_cancel_button', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.comment_body_wrapper').find('.comment_wrapper').hide();
});
```

Note: You can shorten two finds into one selector `.find('.comment_body_wrapper .comment_wrapper')`

Comment: I didn't know this but it works and who doesn't want a `Pythonic` code?.

Answer (score 2):

I seem that you hidding different element than you showing.

You hidding `.comment_body_wrapper` and showing `.comment_wrapper`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with Comment button you are toggling an element with class `.comment_wrapper`, but in Cancel button you are hidding an element with a different class `comment_body_wrapper`.

Then you hide `.comment_wrapper`, and try to toggle `.comment_wrapper`, is a different element so don't works.

You must use the same class in both cases, and then it will work.

```
    $('body').on('click', '.post_comment', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $comment=$this.closest('.post').find('.comment_body_wrapper');
    $comment.slideToggle(); 
    $comment.find('.comment_content').focus();
})

$('body').on('click', '.comment_cancel_button', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.comment_body_wrapper').hide();
})
```

Comment: How does this differ from the existing answers? Best to read the other answers before posting the same thing again.